# Cannot compile simple "Hello World" Java application with native-image on Windows

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-2017, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to compile a simple `Java` `Hello World` application to native code using the `native-image` utility provided by [`GraalVM`](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases) on `Windows` but I always run into errors (see below).

`HelloWorld.java`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

First, I compile the code to a `class` file using the following command:

```
>javac HelloWorld.java
```

Next, I invoke the `native-image` command from the [`VS 2017 Developer Command Prompt`](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Build/Supported+Build+Platforms):

```
>native-image -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces HelloWorld
[helloworld:20420]    classlist:   1,249.05 ms
[helloworld:20420]        (cap):     704.71 ms
[helloworld:20420]        setup:     997.16 ms
Error: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.cpp). Compiler command  CL -IC:\GraalVM\include\win32 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.cpp /FeC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.exe output included error: [Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27035 for x86, Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved., ]
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.cpp). Compiler command  CL -IC:\GraalVM\include\win32 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.cpp /FeC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-2348968769537330415\JNIHeaderDirectives.exe output included error: [Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27035 for x86, Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved., ]
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:114)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.NativeLibraries.reportErrors(NativeLibraries.java:218)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.processNativeLibraryImports(NativeImageGenerator.java:1518)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeLibraries(NativeImageGenerator.java:1006)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:835)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:528)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:445)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

I also tried the `Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt` and the `VS 2019` version but neither worked. How can this issue be fixed? It can't be the compiler since it works for regular `C/C++` applications. Is there anything else you need to configure for this?

Comment: I'm trying to compile a more complex program that I have successfully compiled on linux with native-image, and I'm getting the same error message as you, FWIW.  I'm using graalvm-ee-java8-19.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile successfully using [`JDK 11`](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) and [the respective version of `GraalVM`](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases). A visual guide for this can e.g. be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA4aXFoPoIY) (note: I'm the video uploader).